# TypeError: Konva.Stage is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, konvajs, konva

I cannot find the reason of this error anywhere.

On runtime I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Konva.Stage is not a constructor

at file:///[path]/src/index.ts:40:15
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:197:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

My code in `src/index.ts`

```js
import Konva from 'konva';
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: '',
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
});
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
        "compilerOptions": {
                "alwaysStrict": true,
                "allowJs": true,
                "baseUrl": ".",
                "declaration": true,
                "esModuleInterop": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "incremental": false,
                "lib": [
                        "ESNext",
                        "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
                        "DOM"
                ],
                "module": "esnext",
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "noEmit": false,
                "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
                "noImplicitThis": true,
                "noImplicitAny": true,
                "noUnusedLocals": true,
                "noUnusedParameters": true,
                "outDir": "./dist",
                "rootDir": "./src",
                "paths": {
                },
                "skipLibCheck": true,
                "sourceMap": true,
                "strict": true,
                "strictNullChecks": true,
                "strictFunctionTypes": true,
                "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
                "target": "ES2018",
                "typeRoots": [
                        "node_modules/@types"
                ]
        },
        "include": [
                "src/**/*"
        ],
        "exclude": [
                "node_modules"
        ]
}
```

My `package.json`

```js
{
        ...
        "type": "module",
        "devDependencies": {
                "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
                "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
                "tsc-watch": "^5.0.3",
                "typescript": "^4.6.4"
        },
        "dependencies": {
                "canvas": "^2.9.1",
                "execa": "^6.1.0",
                "konva": "^8.3.8"
        }
}
```

I have checked the code and the library define `Konva.Stage` as a `Class` so why it cannot be costructed?

Can it be something related with ESModule? Maybe the class must be imported in a different way?
But I cannot find a proper example with Typescript.
Is somebody faced the same issue?

Comment: There is a bit of information here : https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/1336